# Как создавать объекты внутри классов придерживаясь DIP?

Tags: php, ооп, зависимости

Представим простую ситуацию. Есть класс `A` в котором есть метод `X`, который внутри должен вызвать метод `Z` класса `B`.

Как это сделать правильно, придерживаясь [принципа DIP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9)?

Если напрямую, в коде `X` описать создание объекта класса `B` и вызов метода `Z`, получится что класс `A` зависим от класса `B`.

Чем меня не устраивает передача имени класса в конструктор `A`? Тем, что в некоторых случаях невозможно передать все зависимости.

В этом примере есть всего 2 класса, но представьте если класс `A`, это контроллер. Например его вызвал роутер, в надежде получить ответ и отдать его клиенту. Классу `A` требуется класс `B`, а ему, в свою очередь, нужен класс `CoolLogger`, например. Не должен же роутер передавать в класс `A` классы `B` и `CoolLogger`, для корректного создания класса `B`. Да и вообще, в этом случае класс `A` обязан знать как нужно создавать класс `B`.

Является ли выходом договоренность о том, что если классу нужна зависимость - он должен обратиться к `классу-инъектору` и попросить создать объект требуемого класса/интерфейса? Если да, то какие минусы этого подхода? Есть ли более крутой подход?

p.s. В этом случае ведь всё равно классы зависят от `класса-инъектора`. Как минимум, они обязаны знать его имя, что бы обратиться к нему

Comment: Обычно это делается с помощью одного из [Creational patterns](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: @hindmost, разве `класс-инъектор` не является порождающим паттерном? Если я не ошибаюсь, это типичный пример "фабрики"

Comment: Было бы здорово, если бы Вы привели более приземленные примеры, не все тут академики :)

Comment: @Peresada что заоблачного в примере с контроллером?

Comment: @TryCatch что такое `класс-инъектор`? Какое дело классу `А` до того, что класс `B` использует класс `CoolLogger`? Ведь по идее класс `А`, будучи "главным" вообще сам устанавливает правила, что он получает. На более приземленных примерах все-таки было бы более понятно, что именно требуется

Comment: `класс-инъектор` это такой класс (например статический), который создает объекты. Это может выглядеть так: `Injector::make('Namespace\ClassName')` / `Injector::make('Namespace\InterfaceName')`. В итоге возвращается запрошенный класс, если он существует. Чаще всего инъекторы ещё и узнают зависимости классов при помощи рефлексии конструктора создаваемого класса и разрешают эти зависимости сами, создавая соответствующие классы и подставляя их в конструктор в нужной последовательности

Comment: Описывая сейчас `класс-инъектор`, я подумал о том, что наверное он мне и нужен. Роутер создаст `A` через инъектор, который сам и разрешит зависимости. Только придется описывать создание специфических объектов, чьи зависимости требуют параметров

Comment: Но всё равно, даже при таком подходе код зависит от `класса-инъектора`. Видимо от зависимостей избавиться нельзя (только в каком-нибудь мета-программировании, возможно). Но в любом случае при таком подходе единственное что придется переписывать при изменении класса-инъектора - те места, где объекты были созданы с его помощью

Comment: @TryCatch Сам принцип DIP подразумевает не избавление от зависимостей, а изменение направления зависимости, поэтому он и называется подобным образом. В данном случае часто прибегают к интерфейсам посредникам, которые и определяют конечный тип объекта, который получит Ваш класс А, а то, что вы называете классом-иньектором, скорее напоминает паттерн Singleton

Comment: @Peresada под "классом-инъектором" я имею в виду `Dependency Injector`, например [Phemto](http://phemto.sourceforge.net)